# Pinescript syntax error when assigning a new value to an array

Tags: syntax, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am currently writing an indicator to determine the POC, VAH, and VAL intraday.
As I am new to Pinescript, it keeps telling me what the assignment of an updated version of the `histogram var` (which is an float array) seems to be wrong, even though as far as I understand it, I am supposed to use the `:=` operator when assigning new values rather than initializing the histogram var.

Here is the corresponding code snippet:

```
// Function to calculate POC, VAH, and VAL
calcVolumeProfile() =>
// Create and initialize a histogram
var float[] histogram = array.new_float(0)

for i = 0 to array.size(dailyPrices) - 1
    price = dailyPrices[i]
    vol = dailyVolumes[i]
    priceBin = floor(price / (syminfo.mintick * binSize)) * (syminfo.mintick * binSize)
    index = array.indexof(histogram, priceBin)
    
    if index == -1
        array.push(histogram, priceBin)
        array.push(histogram, vol)
    else
        histogram[index + 1] := histogram[index + 1] + vol
```

The syntax error appears in the last line where I try to update the histogram value. I am using Pinescript version 4 for this.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript, you can't acces array this way : histogram[index + 1].

You must use array.get(ArrayName, index) and array.set(ArrayName, Index, Value), in you case :

```
array.set(histogram, index+1, array.get(histogram, index+1) + vol)
```